# How to set the Virtual Machine name using Azure Image Builder?

Tags: azure, packer, vm

According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/image-builder) manual one can build an image on Azure using Azure Image Builder. When running the first example, the following error is shown in the customization log:

```
PACKER ERR ==> azure-arm: ERROR: -> RequestDisallowedByPolicy :
Resource '1f43d6s8hd4fr5e' was disallowed by policy
"Virtual Machine Naming Policy"
```

The question is how to set the Virtual Machine image name using Azure Image Builder.

**Attempts to solve the issue**

1. Asked the team that is responsible for the policy to remove are change the *Virtual Machine Naming Policy*
2. Tried to change the VM image name by modifying some keys in the json file.
3. Created the following GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azvmimagebuilder/issues/28).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configuration key:

```json
.
.
"temp_compute_name": "<desired_name>",
.
.
```

Note: Try to keep name short.